# How to configure app.yaml to support urls like /user/<user-id>?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I do the following

```
- url: /user/.*
  script: script.py
```

And the following handling in script.py:

```
class GetUser(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.info('(GET) Webpage is opened in the browser')
        self.response.out.write('here I should display user-id value')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', GetUser)],
                                     debug=True)
```

Looks like something is wrong there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `app.yaml` you want to do something like:

```
- url: /user/\d+
  script: script.py
```

And then in `script.py`:

```
class GetUser(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
        logging.info('(GET) Webpage is opened in the browser')
        self.response.out.write(user_id)
        # and maybe you would later do something like this:
        #user_id = int(user_id)
        #user = User.get_by_id(user_id)

url_map = [('/user/(\d+)', GetUser),]
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(url_map, debug=True) # False after testing

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How does that work?  Are the strings in the `url_map` parsed as regular expressions somehow?

Comment: @Justin: the matches are entirely by regex, with each `()` group being passed as a positional parameter to the relevant `RequestHandler` method.

Comment: Note that a more common approach is to have `app.yaml` route all requests (eg, `.*`) to your app - there's no need to have a separate app per page, or use specific REs in `app.yaml` at all.

Comment: You'll also find many more examples of such regexes in the docs at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html

Comment: This only works when the user_id is a number, and not when it is a string. Any way to make it work in case of strings also ?