# Google appengine rewrite question

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite url for python:

http://localhost:8081/?page=1

to

http://localhost:8081/1

here is my code, but it's not working:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page):
        mypage = self.request.get('page')
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        if mypage == "":
            self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('page is ' + mypage)


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),('/(\d+)', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: If you want to add more code, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5779879/edit).  Dumping code in a comment isn't usually helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in your controller.  It's not Apache-style URL rewriting *per se*, but it gets the job done.  The rewritten parameter is passed as an argument to the handler.

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        if not page:
            self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('page is ' + page)

url_map = [('/(\d+)', MyRequestHandler)]
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(url_map, debug=True)
```

See [How to configure app.yaml to support urls like /user/<user-id>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763425/how-to-configure-app-yaml-to-support-urls-like-user-user-id) for a similar application.

Comment: here is my code, but it's not working?
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page):
        mypage = self.request.get('page')
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        if mypage == "":
            self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')
        else:
            self.response.out.write('page is ' + mypage)


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),('/(\d+)', MainPage)], debug=True)

Comment: When you use regex matching like this, the parameter is passed directly to the handler, not as part of the request.  Instead of `self.request.get('page')`, just use `page`.

Comment: are you means like that self.request.get(page)  ?

Comment: No, when you use regex in this way, you are passing it as an argument to the actual handler, not an HTTP query parameter.  See my updated code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using webapp:

```
class Rewriter(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect(self.request.get('page'))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', Rewriter)],)
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the question, but I think Duan is asking about making "pretty" URLs for end user consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined two mappings for your `MainPage` handler, one that will pass in no parameters ('/'), and one that will pass in one parameter ('/(\d+)'). Your handler, however, expects exactly one argument, named `page`.

You either need to use two different handlers, or supply a default value for the `page` argument, like this:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page=None):
        if not page:
          self.redirect('/%s', self.request.get('page'))
          return
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('page is ' + mypage)
```

For future reference, when you get a stacktrace, include it in your question! Saying "It's not working" and making us guess exactly what's going wrong isn't a good way to get useful answers to your question.